# Espresso : how to click one of image in listview?

Tags: android, android-espresso

Help!!!

i want test android ui in Espresso, but image every time change.

```
listview
 ---FrameLayout
     ---imageview
     ---imageview
 ---FrameLayout
     ---imageview
     ---imageview
```

I try this way, but still can't click:

```
onData(is(instanceOf(ImageView.class)))
                .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listview))
                .atPosition(3)
                .perform(ViewActions.click());
```

error log:

```
com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'with id: is <2131296725>'.
    at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:67)
:DoubanMovie:connectedAndroidTest FAILED
```

Comment: The whole exception text should be longer. Can you show the whole stack trace. The actual error is in the "Caused by" section of the trace.

Comment: onData() requires a data matcher, matching the backing data as the Adapter would return it, not a matcher for a View.

Comment: @haffax is right the matcher in `onData` work on the items of the adapter not on the Views in the `ListView`. Since you already choose a specific AdapterView with `inAdapterView` you can use 'onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listview))...'

Answer (score 3):

I know I am late but it will help to others.

```
 onData(anything())
                .inAdapterView(withId(listviewID))
                .atPosition(0)
                .onChildView(withId(childViewID))
                .perform(click());
```

This will help you to click on particular view inside listview with customlayout

Comment: I removed inAdapterView and it was ok,

Comment: BTW, I had to get ID of the childs by getting views step by step till reaching to the specific child, example:`'RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mRelativeLayout);'` and then `LinearLayout v_storelist_childs_main = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.storelist_childs_main);` and `...........` then for onChildView: `withId(child1.getId())`

Answer (score -2):

try this,

```
((ImageView)((FrameLayout) listview.getChildAt(position)).getChildAt(position)).performClick();
```

this may help you

Comment: is this a Espresso testcase?

Comment: This is not Espresso code. Accessing Views directly like this in a test is very unstable and not recommended.